# Anaconda Navigator Error when starting it

Tags: anaconda, root, prefix, navigator

anaconda navigator is not starting it says

```
 An unexpected error occurred on Navigator start-up
```

I am just starting anaconda navigator

It gives Navigator Error

```
An unexpected error occurred on Navigator start-up
```

Report

```
Please report this issue in the anaconda issue tracker
```

Main Error

```
'root_prefix'
Traceback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\anaconda_navigator\exceptions.py", line 75, in exception_handler
    return_value = func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\anaconda_navigator\app\start.py", line 151, in start_app
    window = run_app(splash)
  File "\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\anaconda_navigator\app\start.py", line 65, in run_app
    window = MainWindow(splash=splash, tab_project=False)
  File "\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\anaconda_navigator\widgets\main_window.py", line 168, in __init__
    self.api = AnacondaAPI()
  File "\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\anaconda_navigator\api\anaconda_api.py", line 2337, in AnacondaAPI
    ANACONDA_API = _AnacondaAPI()
  File "\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\anaconda_navigator\api\anaconda_api.py", line 89, in __init__
    self._conda_api = CondaAPI()
  File "\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\anaconda_navigator\api\conda_api.py", line 1773, in CondaAPI
    CONDA_API = _CondaAPI()
  File "\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\anaconda_navigator\api\conda_api.py", line 350, in __init__
    self.set_conda_prefix(info=get_conda_info())
  File "\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\anaconda_navigator\api\conda_api.py", line 505, in set_conda_prefix
    self.ROOT_PREFIX = info['root_prefix']
KeyError: 'root_prefix'
```

The Anaconda navigator is not starting

Answer (score 0):

Try reset anaconda-navigator

```
anaconda-navigator --reset
```

Answer (score 0):

im facing this error while running of jupyter notebook
so i uninstalled jupyter notebook
and agian install it `pip install jupyter notebook`

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, in my case this error appeared after GeForce Experience update. After uninstalling GE everything was back to normal.

Answer (score -1):

If you're experiencing issues with Anaconda Navigator not opening or launching, the following methods provide step-by-step solutions to resolve the problem. Follow these instructions to address the problem and get Anaconda Navigator working again.

Try deleting the .condarc file first. Location of the file is

C:\Users\'USERNAME'.

**Method 1: Update pywin32**

1. Open Command Prompt.
2. Run:

   ```
   pip install --upgrade pywin32==303
   ```

   If this doesn't work, try:

   ```
   pip install --upgrade pywin32==228
   ```
3. Wait for the download and installation to finish.
4. Close Command Prompt.
5. Open Anaconda Navigator.

**Method 2: Uninstall pywin32**

1. Open Command Prompt.
2. Run:

   ```
   pip uninstall pywin32
   ```
3. Type 'y' to confirm and press Enter.
4. Close Command Prompt.
5. Open Anaconda Navigator.

Sometimes pip version is outdated so keep an eye on that as well. Try command given below to update it as well.

```
python -m pip install --upgrade pip
```

**Method 3: Update Conda and Navigator**

1. Navigate to the Scripts folder in your Anaconda installation directory.
2. Open Command Prompt from this location.
3. Run:

   ```
   activate root
   conda update -n root conda
   ```
4. Type 'y' to confirm and press Enter.
5. Run:

   ```
   conda update --all
   ```
6. Type 'y' to confirm and press Enter.
7. Run:

   ```
   anaconda-navigator
   ```
8. Open Anaconda Navigator.

**Method 4: Update Conda and Reset Navigator**

1. Right-click Anaconda Navigator and choose "Open file Location."
2. Find the Scripts folder.
3. Open Command Prompt from this location.
4. Run:

   ```
   conda update conda
   ```
5. Wait for the download and installation to finish.
6. Run:

   ```
   conda update anaconda-navigator
   ```
7. Wait for the download and installation to finish.
8. Run:

   ```
   anaconda-navigator --reset
   ```
9. Run:

   ```
   anaconda-navigator
   ```
10. Open Anaconda Navigator.

**Method 5: Install pyqt5**

1. Open Command Prompt.
2. Run:

   ```
   pip install pyqt5
   ```
3. Wait for the download and installation to finish.
4. Close Command Prompt.
5. Open Anaconda Navigator.

Follow these methods to troubleshoot and resolve Anaconda Navigator not opening or launching issues.